# Products for the hydrogenation of the cycloalkene in (3R,4R,5S)-4,5-diamino-3-(pentan-3-yloxy)cyclohex-1-ene-1-carboxylic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction, c-c-addition

> Write the products (more than one) for the hydrogenation of the cycloalkene ring in (3⁠*R*,4⁠*R*,5⁠*S*)-4,5-diamino-3-(pentan-3-yloxy)cyclohex-1-ene-1-carboxylic acid. Reagents are molecular hydrogen with Pt catalyst.

My problem here is that the question implies there are several products for hydrogenation of the cycloalkene. I only see one product, where each end of the alkene obtains a hydrogen, and the pi bond is gone. How can a hydrogenation of this alkene result in more than one product?

[image: Why is there more than one product?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hydrogenation of the alkene introduces a stereo centre, thus the products are:

[image: The products!]